# How to hide status bar on click of listview item in fragment programmatically?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notification-bar

I am hiding the status bar on click of `ListView` item in `getView` method.But when I am hiding status bar then `getview` method called .It should not be called.
Here is my code :-

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This line I have added. How to prevent from calling `getview` method when hide status bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once the status bar is hidden your UI needs to be redrawn, as there's more space now. It's perfectly normal that you get calls to getView.

You can either hide the status bar before drawing the list, or clean up your getView method from whatever problems that occur if they need to be redrawn.

*Note:* To hide the status bar for android 4.1+ you can use:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: i have to hide on click of listview item .I donthave to hide in oncreate method.

Comment: I have implemented this code on click of listview item but its not hiding the status bar .